# Send SMS Link body does not show url with equals sign '='

Tags: html, url, sms, href

I am using the following code in my web app:

```
<a href='sms:?&body=https://someUrl.com/ref=12314'>Send SMS!</a>
```

On android devices (tested on Samsung S10, Sony Xperia Compact), the url in the body of the message is cut off at the equals sign.

I have tried using encodeURI() around the url string. I also tried using a \ (backslash) before the = (equals) sign but that did not work.

Has anyone run into the same issue and found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly encode the bit after `body=`. You can do that by using `encodeURIComponent('https://someUrl.com/ref=12314')`, which will give you: `https%3A%2F%2FsomeUrl.com%2Fref%3D12314`.

The whole href value would then be: `sms:?&body=https%3A%2F%2FsomeUrl.com%2Fref%3D12314`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent